Changes to the index.tsx file in React Native EXPO are not saved
Changes to the index.tsx file in React Native EXPO are not saved in the standard project build.
Followed the instructions on the official React Native website https://docs.expo.dev/.
After making changes to the index.tsx file, I am trying to save the file. The file is not saved and a window appears with the text “Failed to save ‘index.tsx’: insufficient permissions. To try again with administrator privileges, select “Try again in Sudo mode”.”. I click the “Retry in Sudo mode” button, enter the user password, but saving does not happen, but another window appears with the error “Failed to save resource ‘index.tsx’: Command failed:

”/private/var/folders/mw/g9zk2wqj777d_n2_bsqkkbwm0000gp/T/AppTranslocation/25211A84-FF66-4F6C-B3DA-41C0E613E447/d/Visual
Studio Code. app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/code” --file-write
‘/Users/ozimkovsergei/Library/Application
Support/Code/code-elevated-IcYdR3iJ’
”/Users/ozimkovsergei/Documents/OZIMKOV
Industries/oi/OiAppThree/OiSail/app/(tabs)/index. tsx“ Error using
--file-write: EPERM: operation not allowed, open ‘/Users/ozimkovsergei/Documents/OZIMKOV
Industries/oi/OiAppThree/OiSail/app/(tabs)/index.tsx’”.

After that I click “Repeat” and everything happens again. The file is not saved.
If anyone knows the solution, please advise.
VS Code development environment.
I click the “Retry in Sudo mode” button, enter the user password, but saving does not happen, but another window appears with the error “Failed to save resource

‘index.tsx’: Command failed:
”/private/var/folders/mw/g9zk2wqj777d_n2_bsqkkbwm0000gp/T/AppTranslocation/25211A84-FF66-4F6C-B3DA-41C0E613E447/d/Visual
Studio Code. app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/code” --file-write
‘/Users/ozimkovsergei/Library/Application
Support/Code/code-elevated-IcYdR3iJ’
”/Users/ozimkovsergei/Documents/OZIMKOV
Industries/oi/OiAppThree/OiSail/app/(tabs)/index. tsx“ Error using
--file-write: EPERM: operation not allowed, open ‘/Users/ozimkovsergei/Documents/OZIMKOV
Industries/oi/OiAppThree/OiSail/app/(tabs)/index.tsx’”.

After which I click “Repeat” and everything happens again. The file is not saved.

Firstly you need to understand what the error says :

The EPERM error in Node.js means that an operation could not be completed due to insufficient permissions. It is typically seen while attempting to write to a read-only file, and it may appear with an EACCES error.

Before proceeding to execute these commands close all VS Code instances :

Delete the node_modules.

Try to install your components or packages once again.
npm install -g npm@latest --force or npm i or or npm i <package name> --legacy-peer-deps


After installing all packages need to clean cache.
npx react-native start --reset-cache or npm cache clean --force



